# using media queries for landscape

Tags: css, responsive-design, media-queries

I used media queries in making my page responsive on mobile but notice that when the device rotates it doesn't effect the media query. How can I use it in a way that it still holds even when the screen rotates(landscape).

Answer (score 0):

You should use Device orientation

Device Orientation

```
@media all and (orientation:portrait) {
   /* Styles for Portrait screen */
}
@media all and (orientation:landscape) {
    /* Styles for Landscape screen */
}
```

for reference : [1) click me](http://www.hongkiat.com/blog/css-orientation-styles/) [2) me too](http://www.javascriptkit.com/dhtmltutors/cssmediaqueries2.shtml)